# Batch Script to Find a Folder inside Sub Folders and get Folder Path

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to come up with a batch file that will perform the following:

1. Ask the user to input a name.  If no name was given, ask again.
2. Search all sub folders from a starting point (say C:\Temp) for that name.
3. If found, I then want to move that found folder and all it's contents to another directory.
4. If not found, let the user know it wasnt found and allow them to try again or the application.

I am not having much luck finding an example of such a script or bits and pieces of it even to put something together.

Comment: I thought my questions were pretty concrete.  Let's try this:

1.  How do i search all sub folders of C:\Temp for a folder named "Apples"?
2.  How do i capture the folder path to Apples so i can use that in a move command (Move "Path\Apples" to "C:\Temp2")?

Comment: read `help for` and try `for /d /r %a in (apples) do @echo move %a \temp`

Comment: "read HELP FOR and HELP IF"  I do not know what that is nor how to get there.  I tried opening a command prompt and pressing F1 but nothing pops up.  I do appreciate you replying but a little more help than just hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. open command prompt. 2.type "HELP FOR" 3.read.

Comment: 1. open command prompt 2.type `for /d /r %a in (apples) do @echo move %a \temp` 3.voilà

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\temp" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="apples" set "folderpath=%%a"
echo "%folderpath%"
```

Comment: i know this is ancient, but could you edit in details as to what each piece is doing? this 'answer' doesn't really help anyone else out as is

Answer (score 0):

breaking down [foxidrive's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17736442)

> ```
> @echo off
> for /d /r "c:\temp" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="apples" set "folderpath=%%a"`
> echo "%folderpath%"`
> ```

### for loop arguments

```
for /d /r "c:\temp" %%a in (*) do
```

**/d** indicates search for folders (**D**irectories) in a folder set

**/r** indicates search for files **R**ooted in a specific path. In foxidrives's example it's "c:\temp". The /r argument also expects a set of files as the condition for the for loop. e.g.

```
for ... (file1.*, another?.log)
```

but in this case, we use wildcard (*) to look at everything

### IF

```
if /i "%%~nxa"=="apples"
```

**/i** indicates to **i**gnore character chase when comparing the strings

**%%~na** indicates to expand %%a *without* the full path

**%%~xa** indicates to expand %%a without a file extension (e.g. .zip, .cmd, .exe). Although, to me, this seems redundant since we already specified /d (directories only) in the for section.

therefore, **%%~nxa** shows *just* the folder name, deleting extension and full path. For example, if you had C:\some\path\myfile.ext in %%a, then %%~nxa would expand to myfile

#### Sources

https://ss64.com/nt/for.html

https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html