# Find a specific folder and copy folder and contents with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, automation, sccm

I am trying to write a batch file that will be deployed with SCCM. The script should do the following:

1) Create a scheduled task (confirmed this works)

2) Creates required directory that will store data. (Confirmed this works)

3) Since this will be pushed out through SCCM, we don't know the path that it'll have so the script will need to search the entire C drive for this folder, it'll then need to grab that folder and copy it over to the directory created in step 2. (This is the problematic step)

4) Run an installer (tested this works).

Question is, how can I accomplish step 3? Below is some code I have tried but it fails

```
dir *TestFolderName*.* /s copy C:\NewlyCreatedFolder
```

and

```
xcopy / "%~dp0 TestFolderName" C:\NewlyCreatedFolder
```

Any suggestions or tips on how to search for the TestFolderName path, capture and move would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed the step where "TestFolderName" is created, although from your xcopy example it seems to imply its where the script itself is deployed to by SCCM.

If that's the case, just use:

`copy "%~dp0\TestFolderName\*.*" "C:\NewlyCreatedFolder\"`

If this isn't the case, please provide additional info and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt. I should've added the snipped of code where I check for the folder where I want to move it to. So in the section before I have

    IF NOT EXIST :\TestFoldername md C:\TestFoldername
    goto Next Step

    :NextStep
      Here is where I need to search for a specific folder name and then move that folder over to the newly created test folder.

Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like someone else was looking for something similar, check the post here to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724449/batch-script-to-find-a-folder-inside-sub-folders-and-get-folder-path